# Update treeview in real time

Tags: python-3.x, listview, gtk3

This is a treeview I am trying.

```
def search_cr(self):
   headers = {'Accept': 'application/x-bibtex; charset=utf-8'}
   jsonget=(urlopen(http://api.crossref.org/works?query.author=Albert+Einstein))
   data = (json.loads(jsonget.read().decode()))

   # First, open a window to dispaly data
   self.crrefwin = Gtk.Window()
   self.crrefwin.set_title("Showing search result from CrossRef")
   self.crrefwin.set_default_size(950, 350)
   grid = Gtk.Grid()
   self.cr_liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str, str)
   self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.cr_liststore)

   for i, column_title in enumerate(["Title", "Author", "Journal", "Year"]):
       renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
       column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
       self.treeview.append_column(column)

   self.scrolw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
   grid.attach(self.scrolw, 0,  0, 1, 1)
   self.scrolw.add(self.treeview)
   self.crrefwin.add(grid)
   self.crrefwin.show_all()
   #This completes `self.crrefwin`. Why it is not created here?

   # Fetching data and updating to cr_liststore
   for i in range(len(data["message"]["items"][0])):
       url=((data["message"]["items"][i]["URL"]))
       r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
       r.encoding = "utf-8"
       api_tups = self.Parser.parsing_read(io.StringIO(r.text.strip()))
       self.cr_liststore.append(list(api_tups[2:6]))
```

The problem is, I am expecting it to append the treeview for each iteration of last `i` loop, as:

```
self.cr_liststore.append(list(api_tups[2:6]))
```

is inside that `i` loop.

But in reality, the `crrefwin` is appearing only after the `i` loop is done.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your are doing this in the main loop of Gtk, which also deals with showing your items. In order to fix this, the Gtk main loop should get the opportunity to render things.

Most likely you can achive that by including the following `while` in the `for i` loop:

```
while Gtk.events_pending():
    Gtk.main_iteration_do(False)
```

This little while loop basically checks whether Gtk has something pending (like drawing your append) and loops till there is nothing else pending.